# PDO & PHP - Problems with Arabic/Cyrillic

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf-8

I have to ask you a tricky question. I'm using PDO and I've problems with UTF8 encoding. All tables are in UTF8 all PHP scripts correctly INSERT INTO them all data (latin, cyrillic, arabic etc.). Meta is properly set to UTF8 too. Said that I've problems when printing data. An Arabic client of mine just sees a lot of **Ù....Ù±Ø‡** instead of Arabic meanwhile a Russian one has a series of ���� for instead of Cyrillic. It's due to the fact they they both run PHP 5.3.

Said that I'm already connecting to database with UTF8 with "charset=utf8" attribute in my DNS PDO but I know that it's supported only on PHP 5.3.6 or earlier versions. At this point I know that the solution is to pass UTF8 with PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND as 4th attribute (array) in my DNS but it still doesn't work. What the heck am I missing? What should I do to let PHP 5.3 understand that I'm playing with UTF8?

Comment: What has DNS to do with this? Cause you mention it in the question?

Comment: Are you serving pages with the proper content-type header? If not, it's probably being set to whatever their local client has as a default. Make sure it's something like `text/html; charset=UTF-8`. Also what's "only on PHP 5.3.6 or earlier"?

Comment: @tadman -- You have that backwards?  "Prior to PHP 5.3.6, this element [charset on DSN] was silently ignored. The same behaviour can be partly replicated with the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND driver option."

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the connection parameters, the version of PHP you are having problems with.  Also, where does the data come from?  That is, is it encoded utf8?